# How can I get exactly this gold lighting and look?

Tags: modeling, lighting

I'm trying to recreate this 2D cicular image design with the same lighting where the gold gets a whitish hue at the upper right fourth of the circle to make the whole image look like real gold with the nice dark red background.

[image]

I was able to recreate the design but I can't get the lighting right when camera view from top view. How do I achieve this same look where the gold has a nice whitish falloff into the upper right quarter? I want to make it look like a nice gold with the nice dark red color around as in the image or even better.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using an HDRI for your lighting - studio style is best because it usually only has one or two light sources that you can "bring in to position" rather easily using a Mapping node. Blender's default Studio HDRI can be found at .../3.3/datafiles/studiolights/world/studio.exr

(NOTE - in the below image, I disabled all *your* lighting - all the lighting comes from the HDRI)
[image: Lights]

If you want to keep the HDRI lighting but keep the original background, use a setup like this, mixing the two backgrounds using the *Is Camera Ray* input of a *Light Path* node:

[image: Lights2]

Comment: hey thank you for sharing!